# Best book to learn about stock market and investing for an absolute beginner?

Tags: stocks, starting-out-investing

I'm looking for a book to read that will teach me about the stock market and investing (how to determine the health of a company and its stock, etc.)... starting from the bare basics.

To give you an idea of how little I know: I don't even know what the NASDAQ, Dow Jones, S&P 500 are. I'd have to google it to find the answer... which I can do easily... but I'd also like to read a book which will teach me these basics and slowly progress me to more advanced concepts.

P.S. I've heard that 'The Intelligent Investor' is a great book, but I'm not sure if it'd be of great use to me based on my current level of knowledge.

Comment: The intelligent investor is essentially a finance text book, it'll be WAY above your knowledge level.  In my opinion "A Random Walk Down Wall Street" and "The Money Game" are the best to wrap your head around some general basic investing principles, before you start dipping in to textbook-like material.

Comment: "The Four Pillars of Investing" is one I would recommend.

Comment: Learn to earn by Peter Lynch is as basic as it gets, and should be given to high school students (along with time to read it). FYI, there is an ongoing, widespread, debate on the merits of picking individual stocks vs picking mutual funds. A case can be made for either; I do both.

Comment: I agree that "A Random Walk Down Wall Street" is good.  I also recommend [The Bogleheads' Guide to Investing](http://www.amazon.com/Bogleheads-Guide-Investing-Taylor-Larimore/dp/1118921283/ref=dp_ob_title_bk).

Answer (score 0):

[*Investopedia*](http://www.investopedia.com/university/beginner/) (click on link) is a very good place to start.

Comment: Please comment on why you voted - 1.

Comment: I actually think this is a good answer. Not exactly a book but its provides unbiased facts. But the only problem I can think is the OP would be overwhelmed with what to search whereas a book will provide information in order by chapter.

Comment: @NuWin if you had clicked on the link you would see that the information provided is organized like a book.

Comment: touché but in my defense it still isn't a book!!!! Jk

Comment: Correct. You cannot dog ear pages, cannot make notes in the margins, cannot highlight lines, would not hear the 'flip' of the pages… but it is free.

Comment: only free if you can get free wifi.